# Citrix Workspace can't add account after reinstall

Tags: citrix

I had Citrix Workspace in my computer and it was good.

Later I installed Citrix Receiver. This installation deleted automaticaly my Citrix Workspace.

I tried to add an account with Citrix Receiver like I did with  Citrix Workspace. But that didn't worked.
I uninstalled Citrix Receiver and I reinstalled Citrix Workspace. Or the reinstallation of Citrix Workspace deleted automaticaly Citrix Receiver.

But now Citrix Workspace too can't add an account.

To add an account I am using the same adress (probably of the server) I used in Citrix Workspace (before the installation of Citrix Receiver).

Why now I can't add an account please ?

OS : Windows 10

The problem is probably due to the installation of Citrix Receiver or due to the reinstallation of Citrix Workspace.

Thank you

Comment: This is probbably not the right exchange for this question but have you tried to uninstall both application and then to reinstall one of them?

Comment: Yes of course I tried. Ah what is the right exchange ?

Comment: It’s probably superuser.com Did you check the event viewer for any errors?

Comment: @Yass if you used Receiver older than 4.4 you can try this https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX137494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is resolved, I think I download a corrupted version.